# Javascript trigger (progressbar) when on screen

Tags: javascript

i am currently making my own 1-page portfolio website for school and i had this cool idea that i want to show how far ive become in some coding languages by using a progressbar, for example, c# = 60% and that would be 60% of a circle. i think i can do that bu using the internet but i would like it to start / end at 60 when i'm scrolling down and it should start the progressbar when it is on screen. i do not know and cannot find on how to trigger the code when the (in this case progressbar) is visible on screen.

note: i am a fairly new javascript programmer and a fairly new user so please explain if i did something wrong.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: You can either use the "IntersectionObserver" or as an easier approach the scroll event from the document, which tells you the current scroll position.

Comment: Your idea is actually a common thing to see on portfolio pages and CV's for people who just graduated from college. Not only is it incredibly common to see (which will keep you from standing out) but it is also rather useless because telling someone you are 60% at C# is not meaningful to them in any way. I think you should reconsider whether this is something you actually want to do. See here: https://resumegenius.com/blog/resume-help/dumbest-resume-trend and here: https://www.reddit.com/r/graphic_design/comments/5ot0lf/using_percent_bar_to_show_skills_on_resumes/

Comment: Dear Stephen. i learned programming 3 months ago. i asked if someone could help me started with where to begin, i appreciate you took your time to comment but your answer is not of a use for me i'm sorry...

Comment: i need to start somewhere ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of triggering an animation when you scroll to 75% of an image's height using the Intersection Observer API:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.animate-me');

const config = {
  root: null, // viewport
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.75
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= config.threshold) {
      entry.target.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
}, config);

images.forEach(image => {
  observer.observe(image);
});
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 400px;
}

.animate-me.active {
  animation: anim1 .7s ease-out;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer">(Scroll down)</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="animate-me">
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

You should be able to translate this to your own use case, but please share more specifics if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me i changed so i only needed to use threshold to check if i was 70% down